# How to treat dual affiliation in a journal article

Tags: publications, united-states, legal-issues, affiliation, china

I am supposed to receive research funds from a Chinese university while I am working for a US university. The issue is that the Chinese university, as a part of contractual requirements, requests fund recipients to place the university name before my current university in the affiliation section of my future publications. I understand that it is common to place my current university as the first affiliation and the Chinese university as the second affiliation. Does this affiliation issue matter legally? Or is it just my choice?

Comment: If you signed a contract that states said requirement, meaning you agreed to the terms, then you may be bound to following through with it. Your best point of contact is your institutions legal contact in this scenario.

Comment: « Future publications » all of them or just the ones you work on together ? You have to be clear or the legal weasels get you...

Comment: The order in which your affiliations are listed should really not matter to anyone. I'm astonished that any institution would even make such requirements.

Comment: @Roland This is mainly because the government pays a reward per publication, which is proven by affiliation on first and/or last authorship position. This is very pragmatic in China: local affiliation = money drops into account within few weeks.

Answer (score 3):

Where did you do the work that the publication is based on? You need to check the affiliation requirements of the publisher, as well as your contractual obligations with the Chinese institution. Maybe write to the journal editor and explain your situation. Most journals state something like "Present the authors' affiliation addresses (where the actual work was done)..." and "If an author has moved since the work described in the article was done, or was visiting at the time, a 'Present address' (or 'Permanent address') may be indicated as a footnote to that author's name. The ***address at which the author actually did the work must be retained as the main, affiliation address***." (emphasis added, from Elsevier archaeology journals, e.g. https://www.elsevier.com/journals/journal-of-archaeological-science/0305-4403/guide-for-authors) and "The primary affiliation for each author ***should be the institution where the majority of their work was done***. If an author has subsequently moved, the current address may also be stated." from Nature Publishing Group (emphasis added). The Chinese institution, which wants to be acknowledged for supporting you, is not legally the primary institutional affiliation for work done in a US institution. You should be wary of misrepresentation, which could violate publishing ethics.

Comment: In my experience: (i) Chinese contracts are typically vague and most rules are top-down hierarchical instructions by word of mouth; (ii) Chinese institutions will dump publication standards whenever money is involved; (iii) going against their wi$he$ will "hurt their feelings", i.e. they will start ignoring the OP in further communications.

Answer (score 1):

In your position, I'd strictly comply with the legal requirements and practice of your current university **in the US**. This is because you're more likely to face trouble and legal issues from an American university than coming from a Chinese university, especially if you're working in the United States.

Chinese contracts are typically vague and strongly biased. However they are also typically not legally binding, particularly within the academic sphere. They now demand you place their affiliation first so that the relevant department will gain access to money awards from your publications (actually theoretically awarded to *you*, in case you were not informed).

If their demands clash with that of your local institution, I suggest you stall the publication of such papers until you don't need their compliance any longer. As soon as you start working against their expectations there will be communication disruption and a change of relationship status. Still, no legal issues, believe me.